# Application never asks for automation permissions

Tags: macos, applescript, mojave, automator, permission

I have created a quick little Automator script to type my initials and the current date. Whenever I try to run the workflow in every other app I am shown a prompt to give that application permission which then adds it to the list found in Security > Privacy > Automation and gives it access to System Events. However when I try to run the workflow on one specific application that I use for work (called posim evo) it doesn't ask for the permission it just gives the error:

```
The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error: "Not authorized to send Apple events to System Events."
```

The app never shows up in the security list. I have already added the app to the accessibility permissions list. I'm concerned that maybe the problem is happening because posim evo is a third-party app that is not from the App Store while every other app I've tested with was downloaded directly from the App Store. Anyone else have the problem or know how to fix it? Im running Mojave 10.14.6 (required for my job) if that helps at all.

This is my script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set (m:month as number, d:day, y:year, t:time) to (current date)
    set customdate to m & "/" & d
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke customdate

    return input
end run
```

it just prints the current date in mm/dd format to whatever textbox is selected.

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the code from your Automator script? It’s difficult to know what the problem is without seeing the commands that lead up to what is throwing the error.

Comment: Sounds like the POSIM EVO app is not a native macOS application.  Judging from their screenshots it certainly doesn't look to be a native macOS application written in ObjC or Swift.  It might be Java or Node.JS / JavaScript / Electron.  It is cross platform and looks extremely similar across Windows & macOS & Web.  I doubt they have two code bases.

Comment: @user3439894 You are correct, I accidentally pasted the wrong thing into my question. I have corrected it now. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesBrickley Yeah I was a bit afraid of that. Its a really old and janky application so I'm sure its not a native app. Is it impossible to allow Automator scripts to run on nonnative apps?

Comment: BTW... If there is no _action_ after the **Run AppleScript** _action_, then `return input` is not necessary in the _code_.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your **AppleScript** _code_ in a **Run AppleScript** _action_ in  **Automator** and it doesn't compile and errors with: **Syntax Error** Expected “,” but found “:”.

Comment: Developers of native apps have to include AppleScript support. Some limited things are provided by default. Other things not at all. See if you can insert your initials and date time stamp into the clipboard then you should be able to paste into the App. “set the clipboard to customdate” should work. Or do shell script “‘foo-bar’ | pbcopy”. Run the script via keyboard shortcut or Dock icon.

Comment: @JamesBrickley great idea Ill give that a try

Comment: RE: "This is my script:" -- The **AppleScript** _code_ you've posted doesn't compile and errors with:  **Syntax Error** Expected “,” but found “:”.